# Way to see if website was updated with rvest?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to web scrape Nike to see when new sneakers drop. I'm relatively new to web scraping and was wondering if there was an easy was to check for differences in the last search or pull information about the date products were posted.

So far I've been able to pull the list of the most recent products by scraping the new arrivals page that's sorted by newest, but can't seem to find information on that page about when items were posted.

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
url<-"https://www.nike.com/w/new-mens-shoes-3n82yznik1zy7ok?sort=newest"
search<-read_html(url)
search%>%html_nodes(css ="div.product-card")%>%html_text()
```

Any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to save a list to your local drive and then each time you perform the query compare the newly obtain list with your previously found list.

Here I created a data frame with today's date and the query from today and saved it to a file named "Nike.csv".  Then I will run this script, determine the newly added and append to the existing file.  You can then open the csv file and see the date of when each shoe was added to the list.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

#Read file of previous found shoes
existing <- read.csv("Nike.csv")

#Retrieve the latest list
url<-"https://www.nike.com/w/new-mens-shoes-3n82yznik1zy7ok?sort=newest"
search<-read_html(url)
shoes <- search%>%html_nodes(css ="div.product-card")%>%html_text()

#Find the differences between the latest list and previous found list
newshoes <- !(shoes %in% existing$shoes)

#Append to the differences to the current list
if (length(shoes[newshoes])>0) {
   df<-data.frame(date = Sys.Date(), shoes[newshoes])
   write.csv(df, "Nike.csv", row.names = FALSE, append = TRUE,)
} else {
   print("No new records found")
}
```

There are way to optimize this and improve on the error checking, but this will get you started.